# "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" but file exists

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am trying to download a `.wav` file from an Azure server (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) using Visual Studio, but I get

`"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`

In addition, the Python code I am runnining cannot load this file, as I get

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

The file is there.
The file is created by the code itself, so I am not sure if this is some sort of encoding issue or anything else.

```
#! python
import os
import sys
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-d_i', help='MAESTRO original corpus directory (input)', default='/mnt/hdd1/AMT/corpus/MAESTRO/MAESTRO')
    parser.add_argument('-d_o', help='MAESTRO renamed corpus directory (output)', default='/mnt/hdd1/AMT/corpus/MAESTRO')
    parser.add_argument('-d_list', help='corpus list directory')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print('** rename MAESTRO wav/mid file **')
    a_attribute = ['train', 'valid', 'test']
    for attribute in a_attribute:
        with open(args.d_list.rstrip('/')+'/'+attribute+'.tsv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            a_in = f.readlines()
        for i in range(1, len(a_in)):
            fname_wav = a_in[i].rstrip('\n').split('\t')[5]
            fname_mid = a_in[i].rstrip('\n').split('\t')[4]
            number = a_in[i].rstrip('\n').split('\t')[7]
            os.symlink(args.d_i.rstrip('/')+'/'+fname_wav, args.d_o.rstrip('/')+'/wav/'+attribute+'_'+number+'.wav')
            os.symlink(args.d_i.rstrip('/')+'/'+fname_mid, args.d_o.rstrip('/')+'/midi/'+attribute+'_'+number+'.mid')
    print('** done **')
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant snippets of your code around these errors that you are getting?

Comment: I've added some code

Comment: Often the cause of this symptom  is that the program is trying to load the file via a relative path, and the program’s current directory is not what you think it is, so the relative path doesn’t work as expected.

Comment: The ```os.symlink()``` function points to an absolute path ```/home/username/hFT-Transformer/corpus/MAESTRO-V3/wav/test_000.wav``` It does create the ```.wav``` file, but it is not readable.

Comment: I found a solution, answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code did not capture the exception where you get a `FileExistsError`. This worked for me:

```
   try:
      os.symlink(args.d_i.rstrip('/')+'/'+fname_wav, args.d_o.rstrip('/')+'/wav/'+attribute+'_'+number+'.wav')

   except FileExistsError:
      continue

   try:
      os.symlink(args.d_i.rstrip('/')+'/'+fname_mid, args.d_o.rstrip('/')+'/midi/'+attribute+'_'+number+'.mid')

   except FileExistsError:
      continue
```

Comment: (1) You never mentioned a `FileExistsError`. (2) You'll now end up with no MIDI if the WAV exists; you should put these in separate try-except blocks.

Comment: (1) Without the try-except, the .wav file was not being written properly, thus generating the ```FileNotFoundError```. (2) I'll modify accordingly